# Android - activity_main and content_main.xml

Tags: android

good morning 
I'm working on android studio
I am new to application development mobile app
well my question is simple I download the android development tool studio and creating my project
res
-layout
activity_main
content_main
which should work in?
thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are speaking of the default templates - in this case your custom code goes in `content_main.xml`

You probably won't need to modify `activity_main.xml`, but it is not forbidden to do so.

Comment: but which of the two should work?